# Where can I find Windows 8(.1) apps updates history?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

On Windows 8.1 I have modern apps auto updates turned on.

Where can I find a history log of these updates?

Comment: in the Options you can disable the autoupdate, now you can check the details again for each app update.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this. Microsoft disabled the ability to view the update details. I suggest you disable auto-update and simply review updates as they come down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updates are logged in Event Viewer.

Go to Applications and Services Logs

```
   Microsoft
     Windows
       AppXDeployment-Server
         Microsoft-Windows-AppXDeploymentServer\Operational
```

Filter by Event 478 to see succesful updates.